# Unexpected behavior from $\lim_{n\to \infty }a^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am computing the limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty }a^{1/n}$

Using the code:

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && a > 0, Limit[a^(1/n), n -> Infinity] ]
```

yields the expected value: 1., but when I give the input

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals] && a < 0, Limit[a^(1/n), n -> Infinity] ]
```

it yields the output 1 again. The answer that I expected is a message saying  that the limit does not exist since the expression $a^{1/n}$ is not defined for negative values of $a$.

I don't know why I am getting the result 1 in the 2nd case. Any suggestion or a clarification of this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please write a title that is not generic... one that actually relates to your question and not *all* questions.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is `a^0 == 1` for all `a /; a != 0`. Look at a plot:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@ReIm[a^(1/n)], {a, -2, 0.25}, {n, 1, 10000}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log", None},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotLegends -> {Re, Im},
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

For `a < 0` as `n` increases, the real part goes to `1` and the imaginary part goes to `0`. So the limit is `1`

Comment: The theoretical difficulty is that $a^{1/n}$ is not defined for negative values of $a$. I expected that mathematica say that such limit does not exists.

Comment: It is defined, it is merely complex.

Comment: Yes, but in the Assuming I established that $a \in \mathbb{R}.$ But now I understand how mathematica  compute the limit.

Comment: Assuming that $a$ — and even $n$ — is real does not make $a^(1/n)$ real in all cases.